# Importance of AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor in AVAssetWriter

Tags: ios, video, avassetwriter

I'm trying to output video captured from the camera using `AVAssetWriter`.

I'm following some examples that don't use `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor` ([Record video with AVAssetWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36859134/record-video-with-avassetwriter)), and some that do ([AVCaptureSession only got video buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257052/avcapturesession-only-got-video-buffer)).

Based on the Apple references, I've interpreted the purpose of `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor` (or `CVPixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferPool`) in general to be an efficient way to buffer incoming pixels in memory. In practice, how important is it to use this when writing video output using `AVAssetWriter`? I seem to be able to get a basic version working without using the adaptor just fine, but I wanted to understand a bit more the benefit/intent of using `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor` in general.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using video recording without the PixelBufferAdaptor for several years without any problems. I essentially use this code:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer  fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{
     if (videoWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData) {
         [videoWriterInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
     }
}
```

My take is that since the CMSampleBufferRef contains timing information it can be written directly. Whereas if you have a CVPixelBuffer you must add the timing information through the adaptor. So if you are doing some image processing before writing you will end up with a CVPixelBuffer and have to use the adaptor. The adaptor might also add some buffering capabilities for the CVPixelBuffer if your processing takes time.